# Multi-table insert in dbt (1 select -> several target tables)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Snowflake supports multi-table inserts:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert-multi-table.html

I'm wondering if there is a way to do that in dbt. Can be useful when you have 1 source table that should be transformed into several target tables. For example, this is a typical use case in Data Vault.